# Not able to add empty view below Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I was trying my hand with recyclerview and floating action button for an app. The problem I encountered is that the floating action button hinders with the buttons in recyclerview. I looked up how the android apps such as phone app(one where you have contacts displayed in gridvew) are designed to deal with this, I see that there is empty space left in the bottom which gives space between recyclerview and floating action button, user just needs to scroll to the bottom to avoid the overlap.
I tried to add a view after recyclerview but not its not getting displayed, also this view should move along with the recyclerview rows. What am I missing to show a view in the end of the recyclerview.
My layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#6fbababa">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button_floating_action"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_fab"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:elevation="2dp"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/my_recycler_view"
        android:background="@color/white"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

**Update:** Modified the layout code to make it work.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView 
android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:clipToPadding="false" 
android:paddingBottom="30dp" 
android:scrollbars="vertical"/>
```

Comment: All you need is to leave the RecyclerView to be drawn last. Check the example on my answer. HTH

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Add bottom padding to the RecyclerView.
Also, don't use `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` unless you've overridden `onMeasure` in the layout manager. Current layout managers do not yet support wrap content.

Add the attribute `android:clipToPadding="false"` to achieve the goal.
As mentioned in comments.

Comment: Adding  padding to the recyclerview is causing a section of the screen to be occupied which is cutting off the view to the row in the end of the screen. Its not showing up empty space below the last row, instead its showing over the lastrow

Comment: Just resolved that issue...we also need to add android:clipToPadding="false" in recyclerview..this is the final result that worked for me
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingBottom="30dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

Comment: @ɥʇᴉɾuɐɹ awesome, you made my day :-)

Comment: Actually it supports wrap_content. The problem is that it does not recalculate after new elements are drawn on the screen. But it works fine for previous elements. So all you need to do is leave RecyclerView last on the layout file. And you can set the element placing with a RelativeLayout. Check my answer.

Comment: This solution makes my bottom view disappear on scrolling up. Anyone knows why?

Comment: android:layout_height="wrap_content" is now supported after support library 23.2. http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html#recyclerview

Comment: To avoid that the scrollbars is clipped you can add `android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay" ` in addition.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example (in this case a listView, but could be anything) underneath a recycler view that takes up the rest of the parent's height.  Note layout_alignParentBottom and layout_above attributes.

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    **android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"**
    />

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_above="@+id/list_view"
    />
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created an utility method for that so you can add padding easily

```
public void addLastChildPadding(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder,int padding,int recyclerListSize,int position){

if(recyclerListSize-1==position){
holder.itemView.setPadding(0,0,0,padding);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this at once

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clipToPadding="false">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/button_primary_color_border"
                android:text="70%"
                android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/button_primary_color_border"
                android:text="60%"
                android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Remove images and other string according to your uses.