# Making StaggeredGridLayout wrap content

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-recyclerview

I need to display a staggered grid within a linear layout.

[image]

For that I have used a `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` on a `RecyclerView` from `android.support.v7.widget`. The problem is that `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` doesn't support `wrap_content`.

There are other questions addressing the issue, but they are concerned with linear layouts, not staggered grids:

- [Not able to add empty view below Recyclerview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27768495/not-able-to-add-empty-view-below-recyclerview)
- [How do I make WRAP_CONTENT work on a RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27475178/how-do-i-make-wrap-content-work-on-a-recyclerview)

As far as I understand I could derive `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` and implement `onMeasure`. Is there a way do to that without recalculating the positions and sizes of the children myself? When looking at the [StaggeredGridLayoutManager.java source](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v7/recyclerview/src/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager.java), I can see that it uses `ScrollbarHelper` to approximate the size of the scrolling content. Is there a way to reuse that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended-up using a custom control for this, inspired by:
https://github.com/expilu/AntipodalWall/blob/master/library/src/com/antipodalwall/AntipodalWallLayout.java

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when RecyclerView is drawn, it calculates all the remaining size to itself before drawing the next elements and don't recalculate after the other elements are drawn, leaving them outside the screen.

There is an easy fix for this problem: The trick is to draw all other elements first, and leave RecyclerView for last. Use a relative layout and put the RecyclerView last on the XML layout file. Since with relative layout you can put each element wherever you want independently of the order on the XML file, you will draw all elements before RecyclerView and this will make it calculate the accurate remaining space and wrap_content will work properly.

Example to add a paginagion bar below the RecyclerView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/pagination_btns"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"> //HERE YOU ALIGN THIS ELEMENT TO THE BOTTOM OF THE PARENT
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/previous_btn_label"/>
        <Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/next_btn_label"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/items_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_above="@id/pagination_btns"/> //HERE YOU ALIGN THE RECYCLERVIEW ABOVE THE PAGINATION BAR 


</RelativeLayout>
```